# use spring jpaRepository in scheduled task without wrapping in transaction

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-scheduled

Is it possible to use a jpaRepository to perform CRUD operations within a scheduled Task (annotated with `@Scheduled`) without wrapping the scheduled method with `@Transactional`?

**Use Case:**

We have a scheduler to pop jobs and each job has certain operations to perform and fetches + saves data accordingly.

```
private void processJob(T job) throws Exception {
    updateJobToTaken(job);
    internalProcess(job); //calls a service to run the job operations
    updateJobToDone(job);
}
```

1- If we don't wrap the method with `@Transactional`, all operations done within the `internalProcess()` are not saved to the DB. So we added `@Transactional(propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

2- This caused a regressions on our `dryRun` flag: We added a `dryRun` flag that is passed to the `internalProcess` method. If the flag is `true`, we skip calling `repository.save(entities)` and expected that none of the work was saved. So we simply logged the changes to the console.

```
if (!dryRun) {
  setupsGroupRepository.save(setupsGroup);
}
```

But since the method is transactional, Spring committed the changes and everything was committed.

**What we would like?**

Controlling DB access explicitly. Meaning if I don't call `repository.save(`), i'm not expecting anything to be committed. And vice versa, when i call `repository.save()`, i'm expecting my updates to be committed fully to the DB.

When we call the internalProcess method directly without having a scheduledTask, everything runs perfectly. but now, it feels that spring transaction management gets in the way at every turn.

Comment: This should help https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-programmatic, make transaction not declarative, but programmatic.

Comment: Calling or not calling save will not make a difference with JPA. If it is a managed entity, changes will be automatically flushed to the database. What you should do instead is manually do the transaction management and with the `dryRun` do a rollback, else a commit.